# Crystal Report viewer 13.0.2000.0 print button not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET webform application that displays a report in the web Crystal report viewer.

After deployment, we realized some users were not able to print the report with the viewer "Print" button with Internet Explorer 11. An "Export to PDF" popup is displayed instead of the print dialog.

Answer (score 1):

After a LOT of trial and error, we found that resetting Internet Explorer 11 parameters (Internet options > Advanced tab > Reset... button > check the "Delete user settings" checkbox) fixes the issue.

I never saw this solution anywhere so I post it here for the benefit of others.